# splitting table

Tags: database, database-design

I have the following table which holds data on customers and staff. Would it be beneficial if I split it into 2 separate tables: Persons and Address? Each single person can have only one address, phone and mobile. I have a separate table for orders.

My database is quite complex and I wonder if this would be useful for implementation.

Many thanks,
zan

```
_______________
Persons        |
_______________|
PersonID       |
FirstName      |
LastName       |
OrderName      |
Email          |
Telephone      |
Mobile         |
StreetAddress  |
City           |
RegionID FK    |
Country        |
PostCode       |
TitleID  FK    |
PersonCat FK   |
MailingList    |
_______________|
```

Comment: "The reason for this is the number of fields and different relationships" is no reason for change.  The questions are one of functional dependency and cardinality.  Can a person have multiple phones or multiple addresses or multiple orders?  If so, then you need separate tables.

Comment: I appreciate the thanks.  It would be better, however, to actually answer the questions I asked.  Please delete your comment.  Please **update** your question with answers to my questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only split tables when it's for normalizing purposes: for example, if one person can have multiple addresses or if less than a certain amount of people have an address (let's say 90%), which would result in a lot of NULL values.

If it's not for normalizing, don't split tables.